# Is there a way to restrict other workbooks to be opened in an Excel instance?

Tags: excel, vba

**Situation**: I am currently stuck on understanding how I can prevent other workbooks to be opened in the same Excel instance as my personal workbook.

**Reason/Attempts**: The VBA code is found within my personal workbook, where I am creating a separate Excel instance `xlApp` and adding my workbook to that instance and removing it from the previous instance `Application`.

Now, whenever I open other files/workbooks, they will be assigned to `Application`, which is what I am looking for; however, if I close all the files I opened, except for my personal workbook, and attempt to open any file again, they will be opened in `xlApp`.

**Goal**: What the program should be doing is opening all other files in the `Application` instance, not the `xlApp` instance, regardless if `Application` has no workbooks open.

Is there a way I can prevent them from being opened in `xlApp`?

```
Public Sub createNewInstance()

Dim xlApp as Excel.Application

Set xlApp = New Excel.Application             'Creating new Excel instance.

xlApp.Workbooks.Add ThisWorkbook.FullName     'Adding my open workbook to that instance.

xlApp.Visible = True

Set xlApp = Nothing

ThisWorkbook.Saved = True                     
ThisWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False        'Closing the workbook of this current instance (not the new one).

End Sub
```

Comment: *Why* are you doing this though? What problem is this instance-swapping solving?

Comment: @MathieuGuindon As I am studying VBA, I was looking to see if this was something that would be possible in doing. There might be situations where I would like to make changes to the Excel instance, without affecting other workbooks in the same instance.

Comment: Don't files *normally* open in Excel in whatever instance was last created? What would a different behavior look like? Excel should stop trying to open files in an existing instance and instead spawn a new process every time? That _might_ be configurable, but if it isn't, then I don't think it's possible to "fix" this programmatically with VBA code, no. Consider editing your post to clarify what *should* happen, rather than what *shouldn't* be happening.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon In this situation, when I created the new instance ```xlApp```, all files that I begin to open are being opened in the ```Application``` instance, which is what I am looking for. The problem is that once I close all the files in the ```Application``` object, new files will be assigned to the ```xlApp``` instance. As I am thinking about it, is there a way I can use VBA code to keep the ```Application``` instance open, regardless if all the files are closed?

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Understood, I have edited my post to clarify what should happen.

Comment: The only possible solution which occurs to me is maybe you can create an [application event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/excel/create-application-level-event-handler) on OpenWorkbook, check the newly opened workbook name, and then close it if necessary. This is terrible user interface design though.

Comment: IMO this is raising every flag of an X-Y problem. Still upvoted for the effort. Good luck!